# Why doesn't continue statement work in this loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm following an example from the book *Beginning JavaScript*, and currently learning *break* and *continue* statements. *Break* worked perfectly, *continue* does exactly the same as *break*, although it should continue to execute code over the rest of the array. Why is that?

```js
var degFahren = [212, 32, "string data", -459.15];
var degCent = [];
var loopCounter;

for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <=2; loopCounter++) {
    if (isNaN(degFahren[loopCounter])) {
        alert("Data '" + degFahren[loopCounter] + 
            "' at array index " + loopCounter + " is invalid");
        continue;
    }
    degCent[loopCounter] = 5/9 * (degFahren[loopCounter] - 32);
}
        
for (loopCounter = 2; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter--) {
    document.write("Value " + loopCounter +
        " was " + degFahren[loopCounter] +
        " degrees Fahrenheit");
    document.write(" which is " + degCent[loopCounter] +
        " degrees centigrade<br />");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is it *why are `continue` and `break` different*? The answer to that would be that sometimes it's useful to continue with the next item (i.e. skip to the end of the current iteration), and sometimes it's useful to totally break out. Is there something wrong with the code? If so, what behavior do you expect, and what do you get? Two tips: Use `console.log` instead of `alert` and `document.write`. The console is better-suited - you'll see everything nicely organized, and see which code outputted it. Also: indent your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: According to my understanding of what I've just finished reading in said book, _break_ is supposed to leave the loop altogether (which is what I'm getting with _continue_), and _continue_ is supposed to skip that iteration and start with the next one (which is not happening here). _continue_ here is not skipping the invalid data, just leaving the loop altogether.

Comment: You are not breaking out of your loop because of continue. You are breaking it because the loop ends. You can't get to the last element in your array because you end the loop when loop counter gets to 3.

Comment: `document.write` is not recommended, use `document.body.innerHTML += "str";`

Answer (score 4):

`continue` is ending the loop because the loop reached its termination condition. Your test isn't based on the array's length, you just exit when `loopCounter <=2` is false. Since the third element in the array (at index 2) is the "not a number" value, whether it `break`s or `continue`s is irrelevant; `break` exits immediately, while `continue` jumps to the top of the loop, increments `loopCounter` from `2` to `3`, then exits the loop because `loopCounter <=2` is no longer true. Either way the loop is done.

If you change the loop condition to `loopCounter < degFahren.length`, you'll run the loop one more time and process the final value in your array when the `continue` occurs (but not if you used `break` instead).

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct; `continue` skips to the end of the body of the loop and goes on with the next iteration.

The loop starts with `loopCounter = 0`. The condition `loopCounter <= 2` is met, so control flow goes into the body, which skips the continue.

After the `for` body, the third code block in the `for` loop header is executed. In this case, that's `loopCounter++`, so `loopCounter` is now 1. The condition `loopCounter <= 2` is met, so control flow goes into the body, which skips the `continue`.

After the `for` body, the third code block in the `for` loop header is executed, resulting in `loopCounter = 2`. The condition `loopCounter <= 2` is met, so control flow goes into the body.

Now, the `continue` is executed since the second element is not a number. It skips to the end of the `for` body.

After the `for` body, the third code block in the `for` loop header is executed, resulting in `loopCounter = 3`. **The condition `loopCounter <= 2` is not met**, so the `for` loop terminates.

If you want to iterate over all elements, change the condition from `loopCounter <= 2` to `loopCounter < degFahren.length`:

```
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < degFahren.length;loopCounter++) {
```

Comment: You don't want it to be `loopCounter <= degFahren.length`, you want `loopCounter < degFahren.length` or you're indexing into undefined values beyond the end of the array.